# Is It possible that Single Angular 2 application has two URL's?

Tags: angular2-routing

Here in my application, I am trying to create the Distributed DBMS with horizontal fragmentation. As my project is from educational domain, I am dividing my DB according to Institutes. At front end we are using Angular 2 framework.
Now there is one conditions that, in our application we are having different user Roles. Depending on role,  User can modify the Institutes attributes.

So Scenario is that,

1. when Admin user will login,he should have institute management page then he should redirect to Home or into application for further processing, so its demo URL will be :- `"demoapp/appdba/login/"` => `"demoapp/appdba/InstManagement"` => `"demoapp/appdba/Home"`
2. If user will be another person than Admin, then after login he should directly navigate to Home page or into application where he can access further menus or functionality. So it's demo URL will we :- `"demoapp/app/login"` => `"demoapp/app/Home"`

Here is my confusion that can we create two different projects for these two scenarios or we can manage everything in single application or project? How can manage this functionality in single project?
 How we can manage two URL's for single application?
Please anyone clear my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this thing with another solution. Make a control database which is the parent of all other databases

Control database

1. TestDemo
2. InstituteDatabase
   etc....

Add your user information in Control database which also contain database information in which user redirect.

Let suppose a user of test demo trying to login. First call goes to Control database and it authenticate the user and give you information of user and its database and you can use it as you want.

Your application remain same but as your user increases, every user or institute has thier own database which will give strong secuirty.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. But I have to add one extra page i.e Institute management for admin only. Other users will not have access or even they will not be aware of existence of that page. How to accomplish this?

Comment: Assign user role as well. If you have two users (Admin and other) then allow admin user to activate that page url. You can add routing service in angular to restrict other users.